# Solving differential equation system with FEM when the equations depend on the mesh cell size

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

I am trying to implement Large eddy simulation with FEM for solving air flow simulation using Smagorinsky sub-grid stress model. In order to implement this there is a parameter (filter size) in the differential equation system that has to be calculated based on the grid size: $\Delta=(\Delta_x\Delta_y\Delta_z)^{1/3} $ where $\Delta_x,\Delta_y,\Delta_z $ is the size of the mesh cell in the x, y and z direction, respectively. Is there any possibility to implement this with the NDsolve function? I did not find any solution in the documentation of the FEM.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Can you show the code of what you have done? This will help others to help you with your question.

Comment: So far I just tried to solve the Navier-Stokes equations directly when I realized it is not possible for large Reynolds numbers. I found that the LES method can overcome this issue, but I have no idea how to implement this step I mentioned in the question. My only idea is to add the mesh cell size dependency with a piecewise function, but obviously this is neither an effective nor an elegant solution.

Comment: The FEM documentation has tutorials on mesh creation and visualization. Including evaluating mesh properties such as cell size. Do those properties help define your mesh-size operator?

Comment: I can find the the nearest cell to a point with the "NearestMeshCells" function and calculate the size. Originally I used "ElementMesh" object and this function works only with "MeshRegion", so I will try to convert to the latter one and check if it works. Thanks for the idea of "mesh-size operator", so far I tried to find a way to take into account the mesh size in the NDsolve function, but I guess there is no such option.

Comment: @Sicsok What kind of flow do you try to simulate?

Comment: @Alex Trounev Turbulent air flow, high Reynolds number, kinematic viscosity: 1.5*10^-5m^2/s, speed 20-60m/s, the space is a cuboid (0.14x0.02x0.03m) with some tubes (D0.003m) inside